# Get repository contributors with Github Graph Api V4

Tags: github-api, github-graphql

Is it possible to get the contributors to a repository using GitHub's graphql api? I've been searching in the explorer and I can't find a `contributor` property or anything like that on the `Repository` node.

[image]

However, it seems that given a user, the api lets you find out which repositories they've contributed to:

[image]

Am I missing something or does the V4 api really not support getting the contributors of a repository?